# More uniform vertical centering text in tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

This is one of those "have your cake and eat it too" questions --- is there a way to more "uniformly" center individual text letters in nodes?

The default vertical alignment does a good job in general by aligning the entire text box vertically centered (at least I think it does), but the baselines are quite different depending on the letter, and a few of the letters look a bit weird. (**b** and **g** and **μ** in particular.)

Any suggestions? My first thought would be to center the baseline-lowercase line somehow.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\s  [count=\i] in {x,y,z,\delta, \mu, \beta, 1, 4, b, g, S, f, k, c, w, l, \rho, \lambda,\nu,\xi, p, q, r, t } {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\row}{int((\i-1)/6)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{mod(\i-1,6)}
  \node[circle, inner sep = 0, minimum width = 5mm, draw=black] at (0.55*\col,0.55*\row) {$\s$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Messing with `text height` and `text depth` sort of works... at least it makes the baselines uniform, at the cost of making some characters look "off" in other ways.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\s  [count=\i] in {x,y,z,\delta, \mu, \beta, 1, 4, b, g, S, f, k, c, w, l, \rho, \lambda,\nu,\xi, p, q, r, t } {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\row}{int((\i-1)/6)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{mod(\i-1,6)}
  \node[circle, inner sep = 0, minimum width = 5mm, draw=black, text height=2.0ex, text depth=1ex] at (0.55*\col,0.55*\row) {$\s$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ultimately this is a matter of personal preference. You can't have the baselines aligned and also have characters of differing heights (and depths) centered. I like `text depth=0` and  `text height=1.5ex`, but that's just what looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could measure the maximal widths, depths and heights of all characters, and use this information to set the `text width`, `text depth` and `text height`. In this example, the text height is set to be the maximal height plus the maximal depth. Whether this is the best choice is a matter of taste. You may want to play with different prescriptions until you find something that find sufficiently appealing.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[measure char/.code={\setbox0\hbox{$#1$}%
    \ifcsname mywd\endcsname
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywd}{max(\mywd,\wd0)}%
    \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywd}{\wd0}%
    \fi 
    \ifcsname mydp\endcsname
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydp}{max(\mydp,\dp0)}%
    \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydp}{\dp0}%
    \fi 
    \ifcsname myht\endcsname
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myht}{max(\myht,\ht0)}%
    \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myht}{\ht0}%
    \fi 
    }]
\tikzset{measure char/.list={x,y,z,\delta, \mu, \beta, 1, 4, b, g, S, f, k, c, w, l, \rho, \lambda,\nu,\xi, p, q, r, t }}
\foreach\s  [count=\i] in {x,y,z,\delta, \mu, \beta, 1, 4, b, g, S, f, k, c, w, l, \rho, \lambda,\nu,\xi, p, q, r, t } {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\row}{int((\i-1)/6)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{mod(\i-1,6)}
  \node[circle, inner sep = 0, text width = \mywd pt,text depth=\mydp pt,text height=\myht pt+\mydp pt, draw=black,align=center] at (0.55*\col,0.55*\row) {$\s$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is NOT one answer. I only tested the 3 solution proposed here, by addig at each one the following line of code (at the begenning of each environnement `tikkzpicture`:

```
\draw[gray!15,step=.55] (-.5,-.5) grid (3,2);
```

I have this result of the comparition for centering:

[image]

For my taste the better is the first one.